# Ionic 3, limit number of decimal characters on ion-input

Tags: angular, ionic3

I've created a custom input component where I've got @Input('numberOfDecimals');
So using this info I want to restrict the number of decimal characters user enters in the input component.

So if the numberOfDecimals is 2 and when the user enters 2.55 he should not be able to add one more number.

I've tried (onkeypress) (onkeyup) (onkeydown) using event.preventDefault() but still on android phone the preventDefault method doesn't apply and return false as well.

If I use onkeydown and rewrite the this.value of the input element then when i try to remove the last digit it doesn't do anything.

also returning from those methods has no effect whatsoever.

Here's some example code : 
The custom component:

`<input (input)="change($event)" role="input" tabindex="1" contenteditable="true" #inputElement [ngClass]="{'input-invalid': regExError === true || invalid === true,'input-valid': valid === true}" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)" [attr.inputmode]="inputMode" [attr.decimal]="decimalsEnabled" pattern="{{inputPattern}}">`

and the .ts code:

```
@Input('numberOfDecimal') numberOfDecimal: number = 0;
onKeyDown(event: any) {
    let value = event.target.value;
    if (this.validateDecimalInput(value)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;            
    }
}

validateDecimalInput(value): boolean {
    if (this.decimalsEnabled && this.numberOfDecimal !== 0 && value !== '') {
        let currentValue = this.value.split('.');
        if (currentValue[1] !== undefined && currentValue[1].length > (this.numberOfDecimal - 1)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

`

Like i mentioned I've tried many options... onKeyUp parsing the event.. checking the keyCode but it's different on android phone.. so you can't run regEx.

Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `return false` instead of event.preventDefault(). As return false takes things a bit further in that it also prevents that event from propagating (or "bubbling up") the DOM

Comment: I've tried that too :( didn't work for me.. I will update my post.

Comment: can you share you code? specifically the component

Comment: There it is :). Thanks.